# how to return a multiple objects

Tags: java, rest, web-services, response

below i mentioned is  my Restcontroller class
i want to return a multiple object , how to do?

```
// Saving the Data
    @PostMapping("/buyContractRequest")
    public ResponseEntity<Contract> saveOneContract(@RequestBody Contract contract) {

        try {
            contract.setOrderId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            Date date = new Date();
            contract.setTimestamp(date);
            Contract save = contractService.saveOne(contract);
    
              MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue = new MappingJacksonValue(save);

             SimpleBeanPropertyFilter filter = SimpleBeanPropertyFilter.filterOutAllExcept
                                               ("buyerId","timestamp","category","orderId");
            FilterProvider filters = new SimpleFilterProvider().addFilter("ContractFilter",filter);
            mappingJacksonValue.setFilters(filters);

            return ResponseEntity.of(Optional.of(save,mappingJacksonValue));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).build();
        }
    }
```

in above example i am trying to return mappingJacksonValue and save also multiple i want to return

Comment: Create a new `class ContractResult { Contract contract; MappingJacksonValue mappingJacksonValue }`, then return that.

Comment: Why not try to return them in a map(or array)?